# Why does python allow spaces between an object and the method name after the "."

Tags: python, python-2.7

Does anyone know why python allows you to put an unlimited amount of spaces between an object and the name of the method being called the "." ?

Here are some examples:

```
 >>> x = []
 >>> x.            insert(0, 'hi')
 >>> print x
 ['hi']
```

Another example:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d            ['hi'] = 'there'
>>> print d
{'hi': 'there'}
```

It is the same for classes as well.

```
>>> myClass = type('hi', (), {'there': 'hello'})
>>> myClass.            there
'hello'
```

I am using python 2.7
I tried doing some google searches and looking at the python source code, but I cannot find any reason why this is allowed.

Comment: Someone in charge (i.e., GvR) decided that whitespace should be ignored when possible. And thus it is so.

Comment: Are you asking "why" as in "where is the code that makes it work that way" or "why" as in "what is the reasoning"?

Comment: The whitespace is actually allowed either side...

Comment: I would like to know  "where is the code that makes it work that way" and "what is the reasoning," if possible.

Comment: Almost all of the languages ignore whitespaces, it is used only to make the code readable to humans. But, Python cares about the leftmost spaces though, i.e the spaces used for indentation. So, you cannot write fancy code like [this](http://www.ioccc.org/2014/endoh1/prog.c) in Python.

Comment: Check the [grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html#full-grammar-specification) for more details.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I don't think the whitespace handling is in the grammar specification.  It's part of the lexical analysis that happens earlier, to create the tokens which are then analyzed using the grammar.

Comment: Moreover, it allows spaces before the dot as well: `foo    .    bar()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `.` acts like an operator.  You can do `obj . attr` the same way you can do `this + that` or `this * that` or the like.  The [language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#whitespace-between-tokens) says:

> Except at the beginning of a logical line or in string literals, the whitespace characters space, tab and formfeed can be used interchangeably to separate tokens.

Because this rule is so general, I would assume the code that does it is very early in the parsing process.  It's nothing specific to `.`.  It just ignores all whitespace everywhere except at the beginning of the line or inside a string.

Comment: Do you know if there there an official documentation about this?

Comment: @Christian: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#whitespace-between-tokens

Answer (score 3):

An explanation of how/why it works this way had been given elsewhere, but no mention is made regarding any benefits for doing so.

An interesting benefit of this might occur when methods return an instance of the class. For example, many of the methods on a string return an instance of a string. Therefore, you can string multiple method calls together. Like this:

```
escaped_html = text.replace('&', '&amp;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>'. '&gt;')
```

However, sometimes, the arguments passed in might be rather long and it would be nice to wrap the calls on multiple lines. Perhaps like this:

```
fooinstance \
    .bar('a really long argument is passed in here') \
    .baz('and another long argument is passed in here')
```

Of course, the newline escapes `\` are needed for that to work, which is not ideal. Nevertheless, that is a potentially useful reason for the feature. In fact, in some other languages (where all/most whitespace is insignificant), is is quite common to see code formatted that way.

For comparison, in Python we would generally see this instead:

```
fooinstance = fooinstance.bar('a really long argument is passed in here')
fooinstance = fooinstance.baz('and another long argument is passed in here')
```

Each has their place.

Comment: "quite common to see code formatted that way" and not need a "\" on line ends either in some such languages, of course. N.B. the style used in this answer, with dots appearing at the begging of "continuation" lines, is more common (in my experience) than the one given in Brian's answer, with dots placed at the ends of such lines.

Answer (score 1):

Because it would be obnoxious to disallow it. The initial stage of an interpreter or compiler is a tokenizer (aka "lexer"), which chunks a program's flat text into meaningful units. In modern programming languages (C and beyond, for discussion's sake), *in order to be nice to programmers*, whitespace between tokens is generally ignored. In Python, of course, whitespace at the beginning of lines is very significant; but elsewhere, within lines and multiline expressions, it isn't. [Yes, these are very broad statements, but *modulo* corner-case counterexamples, they're true.]

Besides, sometimes it's desirable -- e.g.:

```
obj.deeply.\
    nested.\
    chain.of.\
    attributes
```

Backslash, the continuation character, wipes out newlines, but the whitespace preceding e.g. `nested` remains, so it immediately follows the `.` after `deeply`.

In expressions with deeper nesting, a little extra whitespace can yield a big gain in readability:

Compare:

```
x = your_map[my_func(some_big_expr[17])]
```

vs

```
x = your_map[ my_func( some_big_expr[17]) ]
```

Caveats: If your employer, client, team, or professor has style rules or guidelines, you should adhere to them. The second example above doesn't comply with Python's style guide, PEP8, which most Python shops adopt or adapt. But that document is a collection of guidelines, not religious or civil edicts.