# I don't get why my Flask Code isn't connecting to my HTTP method

Tags: python, html, visual-studio, flask, http-method

> **This is my Flask Code, it's supposed to open another Page that welcomes the user who logs in from my html code**

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/success/<name>')
def success(name):
    return ('Welcome %s' % name)

@app.route('/login', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['nm']
        return (redirect(url_for(' success' , name = user)))
    else:
        user = request.args.get('nm')
        return (redirect(url_for('success', name = user)))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app. run(debug = True)
```

> **and this is my html code**

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost:5000/login" method="post" >
            <p>Enter Name: </p>
            <p><input type = "text" name = "nm"/></p>
            <p><input type = "submit" value="submit" /></p>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

> **The html code gave this error in the terminal**

ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(258)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates with error 2

Comment: You seem to have spaces inserted randomly. Without a larger stack trace, my best guess is that `url_for(' success' , name = user))` is failing because of the extra space in `'success'`. Another instance is `app .run()` - I am surprised to see that is not a syntax error.

Comment: @danuker Regarding `app .run()`: I was also surprised by this, and more-so to discover this is [valid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996132/why-does-python-allow-spaces-between-an-object-and-the-method-name-after-the).  Although in OP's code block, the parent `if` statement is incorrectly placed within the `login` function.  This mistake would only be noticed if launching with `python` (instead of `flask run` or a WSGI server).

Comment: Yes, the problem was with the indentation of the "if __name__ = __main__", it works perfectly fine now

Answer (score 1):

Few mistakes:

1. There's an extra space in `success` in the case of post.
2. The`__main__` is not properly aligned.

Here's the fixed code

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/success/<name>')
def success(name):
    return ('Welcome %s' % name)

@app.route('/login', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['nm']
        return (redirect(url_for('success' , name = user)))
    else:
        user = request.args.get('nm')
        return (redirect(url_for('success', name = user)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app. run(debug = True)
```